# Multiplication of matrices stored in lists

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am struggling to multiply lists as matrices in Python.

I have two lists (`weights` and `returns`) and I need to multiply them as: `weights*TRANSPOSE(returns)`.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you post the code where you're trying to do this?

Comment: This "matrices" look like vectors to me. What dimension are your lists/matrices?

Comment: It seems you are working with some sort of spreadsheet software. Not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are Weights and Return defined in your code?
You might be able to do the following:

```
#This sums the entries
matrixProduct = 0
for i in range(len(Weights)):
    matrixProduct+= Weights[i]*Return[i]

#In case you meant to keep products of individual pairs of matrix entries (not sure from your notation):
matrixProduct = []
for i in range(len(Weights)):
    matrixProduct.append(Weights[i]*Return[i])
```

Comment: Also, the number of items in each of the two matrices is not the same. It is therefore not possible to get a single result.